# Facebook page tab, trying to echo facebook graph data, but can't get it to work

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I am trying to make an app instance for my facebook page tab.

I have done this before, but for some reason I can't seem to retrieve any of the user graph information, and cannot echo any graph info on the page. I have tried my viewing my page tab on multiple user accounts to test, all doing the same.

So I went right back to the beginning and started a fresh using the examples from the sdk on github. But can't even get them to work!!

Please see my application instance (this is taken straight from: https://raw.github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/master/examples/example.php

And I am using the latest sdk: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

```
<?php

require 'facebook-php-sdk-98f2be1/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '----------------',
  'secret' => '---------------------------------',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>php-sdk</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>php-sdk</h1>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
    <?php else: ?>
      <div>
        Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
        <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>PHP Session</h3>
    <pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <h3>You</h3>
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">

      <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
    <?php else: ?>
      <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
    <?php endif ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

No for some reason, it is asking me log in, when I am already logged it?

The php must be error free because it is working - but seems to never work let me connect to see my graph.

And I click login, I just see this screen...

[image]

These are my apps settings in developers facebook...

[image]

Obviously you can see any of my URL's but these 100% are thee right credentials through out.

Can any one please test the code and see if they get the same result. I am using the latest php SDK at: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

---

I am trying to simply echo the current facebook user 'name' using this,

But can even do that, so have back-tracked the the git hub examples to see if I could get the example app instance to work, but it always says 'You are not connected.'

Help or suggestions would be great thanks, I have tried most things..

Comment: You did pass appID and secret to your Facebook Instance, didn't you?

Answer (score 0):

The values in your code are stored in an array under the $user_profile variable. So, for example, the name would be $user_profile['name']. This line of code:

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

is basically saying, query http://graph.facebook.com ...and then adds /me to the end of the URL which is the current user of your app. If you go to http://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID you'll see that it's all an array and you can see what variables you can access with $user_profile.

Basically add an array value and you're set.